# XElement: a collection of all the leaves?

Tags: c#, linq, xelement

how to get a collection of all the leaves of a XElement tree regardless the hierarchy?
Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Is the [`Descendants()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.descendants.aspx) method what you're after?

That will get *all* descendants - to get only the leaves, you could use LINQ to Objects with a `Where` clause:

```
element.Descendants()
       .Where(desc => !desc.Elements().Any());
```

(Note this is still only elements, not other nodes like text nodes. Hope that's okay.)